# Reasons for Win32Exception: "Error creating window handle" even when handlecount and GDI objects less than 10.000

Tags: c#, winforms

I try adding an user control to a panel, like in the code snippet below. It works serveral times. The exception only occurs when I try adding an InputElement to the sixth "hierarchy level" of panels. I'm building a tree of different equipment to visualize a teststation. It doesn't matter how "wide" the tree is, it works, but if I increase the height or rather the tree depth to six, the exception occurs.

I already checked my handles, GDI objects etc. a few times but they are far under the maximum amount. When I reproduce the exception the handlecount is around 800 handles. So I really don't know why it doesn't work.
What are other reasons for that exception?

```
if(dropPanel.Controls.Count > 0)
    foreach(Control control in dropPanel.Controls)
        control.Dispose();
InputElement = new TeststationElement(OutputElement, output) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
dropPanel.Controls.Add(InputElement);
```

It also doesn't matter what control I try to add. A simple textbox also isn't working. I reviewed the whole code, disposed objects, but the error occurs anyway...

Comment: Don't use a `foreach` loop here, use a backwards `for` loop. Are you also disposing of the disposable objects created by the `TeststationElement` class and/or whatever is `OutputElement`? No idea what a *sixth "hierarchy level" of panels* is. See that you're disposing of the objects you create in any *hierarchy level*.

Comment: Pretty standard bug, your foreach loop doesn't dispose all the controls.  It modifies the Controls collection, in effect you only dispose half of them.  That doesn't last forever, eventually you've got too many undisposed ones and the OS stops you from creating more.  Correct code is while (dropPanel.Controls.Count > 0) dropPanel.Controls[0].Dispose();.  There might be more, use Task Manager's Processes tab and add the USER Objects column.  A steadily rising number for your program spells doom.

Comment: Yes, OutputElement is also a TeststationElement. 
Hard to explain here, I meant that it's the sixth panel in a panel...panel in a panel in a panel. And the objects in the other "levels" shouldn't be disposed, cause they can be used. When I delete an object from a panel I already dispose it.

Comment: I also already checked the amount of User objects in the process explorer. I never had over 1.000.